# What is the rationale behind the method behind generation of normally distributed vectors?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

For a long time, I thought that a normally distributed vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ was generated in the following way

> Sample $x_i$ from a Gaussian distribution, $x_i = \mu +
>  \sigma^2\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is a normally distributed value. Then form a vector $x = (x_i)$.

However, I recently discovered that in fact the approach is,

> Let $C$ be a covariance matrix. Factorize covariance matrix $C$ using
> Cholesky decomposition, $C = AA^\top$, where $A$ is lower triangular.
> Then $x = m + A  \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, I)$, where $m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the mean vector, $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, I)$ is a normal vector

- Are these approach one and the same? I am guessing not because the
  first way is assuming a uniform variance.

  Which is more correct?

  And what is the rationale behind factorizing $C$ using Cholesky
  decomposition.

Comment: As described, your second method will generate a normally distributed vector $\ x\ $ with covariance matrix $\ ACA^\top\ $, which I suspect is not what it is supposed to be doing.  For $\ x\ $ to have covariance matrix $\ C\ $ (which I suspect is what was *actually* wanted), you need to put $\ x=m+Ay\ $, where $\ y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n\ $ are independent standard normal variates—that is, $\ y\sim{\cal N}\big(\mathbf{0},I_{n\times n}\big)\ $.

Comment: That was my typo. Thanks for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original approach, if you want $\ \sigma\ $ to be the standard deviation of $\ x_i\ $ you should have $\ x_i=\mu+\sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1)\ $, rather than $\ x_i=\mu+\sigma^2\mathcal{N}(0,1)\ $.  If you do that, your original approach is just a special case of the second, in which your generated $\ x_i\ $ will be independent normal variates with mean $\ \mu\ $ and variance $\ \sigma^2\ $—that is, $\ m=(\mu,\mu,\dots,\mu)\ $ and $\ C=\sigma^2I_{n\times n}\ $.

Which approach is "correct" depends entirely on what you want to do.  If all you want to do is generate a sequence of independent, normally distributed , random variables, all with mean $\ \mu\ $ and variance $\ \sigma^\ $, then your original approach is perfectly fine, but if you want to generate a random vector which is multivariate normally distributed with mean $\ \big(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n\big)\ $ and a covariance matrix $\ C\ $ that is not just a multiple of the identity, then your original approach cannot do that, and you'd have to resort to something like the second.

It's not necessary for the $\ A\ $ you use in the second approach to be obtained from the Cholesky decomposition, merely that it satisfy the equation $\ AA^\top=C\ $. However, since the Cholesky decomposition gives you an $\ A\ $ that's lower triangular, it will then require less work to calculate the product $\ A\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},I)\ $ than if $\ A\ $ were filled entirely with non-zero entries.